# Unable to get delete/put working with express REST

Tags: node.js, rest, express

```
//api.js
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urls = require('../util/enums').urls;
var transaction = require('../controllers/transaction');

router.route(urls.API.TRANSACTIONS)
.get(transaction.getAll)
.post(transaction.addNewTransaction);

router.route(urls.API.TRANSACTION_INFO)
.get(transaction.findTransactionById);

router.get(urls.API.TRANSACTION_DEL, function(req,res){
    console.log('I am in delete');
    res.send('success');
});


router.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send("Now we are in API.js")
})


module.exports = router;
```

With the above code in place i am getting a successful response.

But as i change the method to delete in the above code as follows

```
router.delete(urls.API.TRANSACTION_DEL, function(req,res){
    console.log('I am in delete');
    res.send('success');
});
```

I get this error stack

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
at parse (/Users/Rish/rishcreations/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
at /Users/Rish/rishcreations/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
at invokeCallback (/Users/Rish/rishcreations/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
at done (/Users/Rish/rishcreations/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/Rish/rishcreations/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:308:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Any ideas whys this happening?
I am using postman to make request, everything works fine, except this delete.

Yes i am saving and restarting server automatically using forever.

Comment: How are you sending your put request ? POSTMAN ? Are you doing it from command line ? Can you give more details on the headers/parameters of you request ?
The js you provided looks fine. How are you launching your server ? Maybe the source wasn't updated

Comment: Please provide full error stack.

Comment: @clemkoa I am using postman, no headers or params, its not even reaching the console.log statement. Yes it looks alright to me, plus it works if i make it a get request, but not when i change to delete

Comment: What is the `urls.API.TRANSACTION_DEL` string? Sounds like maybe there's a dash in it.

Comment: @thomas  its basically this --  '/api/transactiondelete' I prefer keeping a utility files for less typos hence the constant

Comment: And what is `req`? Looks like body-parser is choking on something there maybe..

Comment: req,res are standard callback params. It works perfectly fine if i am trying the same with GET, when i change it to DELETE its failing

Comment: And if you try POST or PUT it is the same error ? Basically everything but GET ?

Comment: No POST works, only PUT and DEL are giving issues

Comment: Which version of Express & Node are you using ? If you want to put the code on a public repo I'd be happy to try to find the error

Comment: "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "forever": "^0.15.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.4"

node v.0.12.1

How do i share the repo link